# Intercepting Service calls while using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, service, intercept

Am working on an application where on clicking on a button, a  service call is made.I would like to intercept that Service call and inject a customized response.
This is being done to test the Error handling capability of the application.
We are using Java for Automating this. Would like to know if this can be done?

Scenario:
1.Click on a button(Service calls runs on background)
2.Intercept the service calls to return an Error code

Any pointers are highly appreciated

Comment: If you can change the production code you could inject a mock before the test. If not, maybe you should have to look to some AOP solution (AspectJ for example) and intercept the JVM calls.

Comment: Nope...No changing production code!

Comment: Then have a look to Pointcuts, Arounds and so in AspectJ. It would help you to intercept method calls and change returns values. Like this: http://octodecillion.com/blog/aop-advice-as-mocks/

Answer (score 2):

I recommend wiremock for this:
http://wiremock.org/

You can use it both to mock responses and to verify it's been called correctly by your application. :)

Comment: Looks like a good option.But there is no way i can add the dependencies to the POM. The build file is  common for our framework(used by many) and cant make any changes over there(read only).

Comment: @Nth-Tester You can't add dependencies at all to your project? Well that certainly limits your options. Can't really help you then, sorry.

Comment: It seems the project has yet to evaluate that the testing app is not necessarily the same as the AUT application under test...